# How to limit the sample in the admin panel

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I have a models

```
class Section(CommonFields):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Раздел'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Разделы'

    leaf = False
    top_content = HTMLField(verbose_name=u'Блок контента сверху', blank=True, null=True)
    bottom_content = HTMLField(verbose_name=u'Блок контента снизу', blank=True, null=True)

    def get_min_price(self):
        items_ids = self.tree.get().children.values_list('object_id', flat=True)
        return Item.objects.filter(id__in=items_ids, show=True).aggregate(Min('price'))['price__min']

class Item(CommonFields):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Товары'

    leaf = True
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=u'Цена', blank=True, null=True)
    old_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=u'Старая цена', blank=True, null=True)
    sale = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'Скидка', default=False)
    hit = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'Хит продаж', default=False)
    property = HTMLField(verbose_name=u'Характеристики', blank=True, null=True)
    content = HTMLField(verbose_name=u'Контент', blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.ManyToManyField('FeatureValue', verbose_name=u'Характеристики товара', related_name='items', blank=True)


class Feature(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Характреистика'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Характеристики'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Название')
    section = models.ForeignKey('Section', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=u'Раздел', default=None)

class FeatureValue(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Значение характеристики'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Значения характеристик'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.value

    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Значение')
    feature = models.ForeignKey('Feature', verbose_name=u'Характеристика', default=None)
```

I want to see in the field of characteristics only those characteristics in which the section with the goods section coincides.
I m use formfield_for_manytomany to filtering objects
But its no working/ I m read offical documentation to Django 1.7.7

In admin.py

```
class ItemAdmin(CatalogItemBaseAdmin):
    model = Item
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['formfield_callback'] = partial(self.formfield_for_dbfield, request=request, obj=obj)
        return super(ItemAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)



    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name != "feature":
            kwargs.pop('obj', None)
        return super(ItemAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        item = kwargs.pop('obj', None)
        if db_field.name == "feature" and item:
            section = item.tree.get().parent
            kwargs['queryset'] = FeatureValue.objects.filter(feature__section=section)
        return super(ItemAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

But its no working. Help me please

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "its no working"? Is there any error message involved? What did you tried to find the exact part that is not working? That's a lot of code...

Comment: In ItemAdmin all characteristics are derived, beyond the envy of their "section". I thin dont work part code in admin.py